# WSO2 Identity Server back to login

Tags: jsp, wso2-identity-server

i am just starting out with wso2 Identity Server, version 5.11.
I have modified the login page, now I would like to create a button/link on subsequent pages, e.g. on the TOTP page, to return to the login page. Does anyone have an idea how to do the redirect. Thank you.

I am trying to find resources to do the jsp thing, I have not found much.

Answer (score 1):

The releavant jsp file for TOTP can be found in `/wso2is-5.11.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/totpauthenticationendpoint/totp.jsp`

To add button/links for on subsequent pages, you will have to create a extensions folder inside the relevant authentication folder (ex:totpauthenticationendpoint) and create a jsp file which includes your changes. And then you can import the changes as below

Ex;

```
    <%
        File productFooterFile = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("extensions/product-footer.jsp"));
        if (productFooterFile.exists()) {
    %>
    <jsp:include page="extensions/product-footer.jsp"/>
    <% } else { %>
    <jsp:include page="includes/product-footer.jsp"/>
    <% } %>

    <!-- footer -->
```